# Меняется шрифт при переводе страницы google translate

Tags: html, css, шрифты, jekyll, web-fonts

Я использую шрифт `caladea` которий скачал и подключил в `<head>`.

```html
<link href="{{"fonts/fonts.css" | relative_url }}" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Сам файл `fonts.css`

```css
/* caladea-regular - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Caladea';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('../fonts/caladea-v7-latin-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local(''),
       url('../fonts/caladea-v7-latin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/caladea-v7-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/caladea-v7-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/caladea-v7-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/caladea-v7-latin-regular.svg#Caladea') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
/* caladea-italic - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Caladea';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('../fonts/caladea-v7-latin-italic.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local(''),
       url('../fonts/caladea-v7-latin-italic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/caladea-v7-latin-italic.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/caladea-v7-latin-italic.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/caladea-v7-latin-italic.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/caladea-v7-latin-italic.svg#Caladea') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
/* caladea-700 - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Caladea';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url('../fonts/caladea-v7-latin-700.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local(''),
       url('../fonts/caladea-v7-latin-700.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/caladea-v7-latin-700.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/caladea-v7-latin-700.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/caladea-v7-latin-700.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/caladea-v7-latin-700.svg#Caladea') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
/* caladea-700italic - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Caladea';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url('../fonts/caladea-v7-latin-700italic.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local(''),
       url('../fonts/caladea-v7-latin-700italic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/caladea-v7-latin-700italic.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/caladea-v7-latin-700italic.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/caladea-v7-latin-700italic.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/caladea-v7-latin-700italic.svg#Caladea') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Но когда я перевожу страницу с помощью встроенного переводчика в google chrome шрифт меняется и становиться без засечек.
При переводе страниц на других сайтах я такого не замечал, как мне исправить такую проблему?

Пример текста без перевода:
[image: Текст без перевода google]

С переводом google translate:
[image: Текст з переводом]

Comment: Если вы подключили шрифт без русских символов, то довольно логично, что русские символы не могут отрисоваться этим шрифтом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогла вот эта строчка кода css

```css
html.translated-ltr body {
    font-family: 'Caladea';
}
```

Comment: Как она помогла?